# Why is the output shown for so less duration?

Tags: android, toast

Can you please tell why the the output disappears so quickly?

If you want to run the code, you will need the following in your Androidmanifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Below is the code:

```
package prototype.networking.textfiles;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------- OpenHttpConnection()------------------------------------------------//
    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException
    {
            InputStream in = null;
            int response = -1;
            URL url = new URL(
                    urlString);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
            try
            {
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.connect();
                response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                if(response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
                {
                    in = httpConn.getInputStream();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new IOException("Error connecting");
            }
            return in;
            } 
            //--------------------------------------------------OpenHttpConnection ends here-------------------------------------------------------------//
            //--------------------------------------------------Download Plain Text Files (RSS) --------------------------------------------------------------//
    private String DownloadText(String URL)
    {
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;
        InputStream in = null;
        try 
        {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
        } 
        catch (IOException e1) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e1.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)       .show();
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        int charRead;
        String str = "";
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
        try 
        {
            while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer))>0)
            {
                //---convert the chars to a String---
                String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
                str += readString;
                inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
            }
            in.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getLocalizedMessage(),    Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show();
            e.printStackTrace();            
            return "";
        }
        return str;
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------DownloadText() ends here--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //-------------------------This method downloads "PLAIN TEXT FILES"-------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String str = DownloadText("http://www.appleinsider.com/appleinsider.rss");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG)  .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: please check to see if there is any exception message in the LogCat

Comment: what issues you are facing and paste your error if any issues

Comment: Mr. Agrawal, there is no error. When I run my app, I see the name of my Activity class. I see the output(html page) for about one second and then it disappears immediately.

I tried increasing the duration of Toast class but to no avail.
here it is:

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        String str = DownloadText("http://www.kvk.pravara.com/weather.html");
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, 100000) .show();
    }

Comment: @Chunhui I checked there are no exception messages in the LogCat.

Here are some of the last messages from LogCat:

Comment: 04-06 15:37:06.661: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity prototype.networking.textfiles/.MainActivity: 8461 ms (total 8461 ms)
04-06 15:37:07.941: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
04-06 15:39:36.795: DEBUG/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: `Toast`s are supposed to be shown for short time: [Toasts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

Comment: Exactly how long time is "so quickly"?

Comment: @Agarwal - No errors. The only issue is that the output vanishes within one second. I tried increasing the duration in the Toast() but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "the output vanishes within a secon". But you show it in a `Toast`. And that is what a Toast is supposed to do: check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) - "The notification automatically fades in and out, and does not accept interaction events". It is the desired functionality, not an issue.

The length of a Toast is either `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` or `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`. If you want to show a notification for a longer period of time consider using custom `Dialog` or `DialogFragment` or StatusBarNotification. Or if you don't want it to disappear, simply put it inside a View, e.g. `TextView`.